# Way to link to first (leftmost) tab in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Chrome bookmark pointing to a time tracking spreadsheet I have created.

Every month I add a new tab for the new month, which becomes the first (leftmost) tab.

Unfortunately this causes my bookmark to "break" in that it will load the previous month's tab (which makes sense as I'm linking to that tab... heh).

Is there a way to indicate in the URL a request for the "first" (leftmost tab), rather than a particular tab ID? Seems like a useful feature...

(Eg, `?tabid=1` or something...)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out a simple workaround for this as an answer... pretty obvious but sometimes you have to take the long way around!

If you use the Share > Copy Link feature it will give you a link like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_ID/edit
```

Visiting this URL will load you into the leftmost tab (and then do some kind of URL redirect to the leftmost tab's ID).

So just update your bookmark URL to this `/edit` path and you are good to go!